# Is it possible to modify data in the ingestion mapping using Azure Data Explorer?

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

Im trying to ingest data from a json file and generate new columns with transformed data.

Im trying to do sth like that but cannot find the way to solve it.

```
.create table example ingestion json mapping "example_mapping" 

    '['
        '{   "column":"timestamp", "Properties": {"Path":"$.timestamp"}},'
        '{   "column":"rawValue", "Properties":{"Path":"$.rawValue"}},'
        '{   "column":"Name", "Properties":{"Path":"$.Name"}},'
        '{   "column":"Name1", "Properties":{"ConstantValue":"$.split(Name, "_")[1]"}},'
        '{   "column":"Name2", "Properties":{"Path":"$[\' split(Name, "_")[1]\']"}},'
        '{   "column":"Name3", "Properties":{"Path":"$[\' split(Name, "_")[2]\']"}},'
        '{   "column":"Name4", "Properties":{"Path":"$[\' split(Name, "_")[3]\']"}},'
        '{   "column":"Name5", "Properties":{"Path":"$[\' split(Name, "_")[4]\']"}},'
        '{   "column":"Name6", "Properties":{"Path":"$[\' split(Name, "_")[5]\']"}},'
        '{   "column":"Name7", "Properties":{"Path":"$[\' split(Name, "_")[6]\']"}},'
        '{   "column":"Name8", "Properties":{"Path":"$[\' split(Name, "_")[7]\']"}},'
        '{   "column":"RelevantData", "Properties":{"Path":"$[\'RelevantData\']"}}'
    ']'
```

Name1, 2, 3, 4... are the new columns and Im trying to do a `splitsplit(Name, "_")[0]`
in order to make the transformation in th eingestion mapping.

¿Anybody knows if this is possible? Advice would be welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### Short answer:

Not supported as part of [data mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/mappings)

###### Detailed answer:

[JSONPath expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/jsonpath) supports `$`, `.`, `['property']` or `["property"]` and `[n]`.
[Mapping transformations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/mappings#mapping-transformations) adds some additional capabilities around **source file info** (path & line number),  **unix-time** (transformation to datetime) and **transformation of JSON array of properties** to dictionary.

###### Solution:

This logic can be implemented with [Update Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/updatepolicy)

###### P.S.

Please note that arrays' indexes start with 0

###### Demo:

Create a staging table

```
.create table exampleStg (timestamp:datetime, rawValue:string, Name:string)
```

---

```
// This will keep the staging table empty
.alter-merge table exampleStg policy retention softdelete = 0s
```

---

Create a final table

```
.create table example (timestamp:datetime, rawValue:string, Name:string, Name1:string, Name2:string, Name3:string, Name4:string, Name5:string, Name6:string, Name7:string, Name8:string)
```

---

Create a function that is doing the data transformation from the staging table to the final table.
Please note that within the context of update policy, the staging table name stands for a batch of new ingested data and not the entire data.

```
.create-or-alter function transform_exampleStg_to_example()
{
    exampleStg
    | extend Name_array = split(Name, "_")
    | extend Name1 = tostring(Name_array[0]), Name2 = tostring(Name_array[1]), Name3 = tostring(Name_array[2]), Name4 = tostring(Name_array[3])
    | extend Name5 = tostring(Name_array[4]), Name6 = tostring(Name_array[5]), Name7 = tostring(Name_array[6]), Name8 = tostring(Name_array[7])
    | project-away Name_array
}
```

---

Define the update policy

```
.alter-merge table example policy update @'[{"IsEnabled": true, "Source": "exampleStg", "Query": "transform_exampleStg_to_example()", "IsTransactional": true, "PropagateIngestionProperties": true}]'
```

---

```
.ingest inline into table exampleStg with (format="JSON") <|
{"timestamp":"2022-07-13 13:33:33","rawValue":"Hello","Name":"aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd_eee_fff_ggg_hhh"}
{"timestamp":"2022-07-14 14:44:44","rawValue":"world","Name":"aa_bb_cc_dd_ee_ff_gg_hh"}
```

---

```
.ingest inline into table exampleStg with (format="JSON") <|
{"timestamp":"2022-07-15 15:55:55","rawValue":"!","Name":"a_b_c_d_e_f_g_h"}
```

---

```
exampleStg
```

| timestamp | rawValue | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |

---

```
example
```

| timestamp | rawValue | Name | Name1 | Name2 | Name3 | Name4 | Name5 | Name6 | Name7 | Name8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-13T13:33:33Z | Hello | aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd_eee_fff_ggg_hhh | aaa | bbb | ccc | ddd | eee | fff | ggg | hhh |
| 2022-07-14T14:44:44Z | world | aa_bb_cc_dd_ee_ff_gg_hh | aa | bb | cc | dd | ee | ff | gg | hh |
| 2022-07-15T15:55:55Z | ! | a_b_c_d_e_f_g_h | a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h |

Comment: @Matìas Fernàndez. Saw your edit suggestion (and rejected). Please note the use of `policy retention softdelete = 0s` which keeps the staging table empty.

Answer (score 3):

A good practice to achieve this is using a staging table and an [update policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/updatepolicy) to propagate the data to the target table:

(1) Create a  raw table, where data is initially ingested. This table stores the original json data:

```
.create table raw (d : dynamic)
```

(2) Create an ingestion mapping for the raw table:

```
.create table raw ingestion json mapping "ingest-raw"' [{"column":"d","Properties":{"path":"$"}}]'
```

(3) Create the table with the transformed data:

```
.create table measurement (deviceId:string, enqueuedTime:datetime, temperature:real)
```

(4) Define the data transformation from the raw to the measurement table

```
.create-or-alter function 
with (docstring = 'update policy for measurement', folder='PBI')
rawtransform()  {
raw
| extend m=todynamic(d.measurement)
| mv-expand (m)
| extend deviceId=tostring(m.header.deviceId), 
enqueuedTime=todatetime(m.header.enqueuedTime), 
temperature=toreal(m.temperature)
| project-away d, m}
```

(5) Define an update policy definition for the measurement table, with this new ingested data to table raw will be inserted in the measurement table

```
.alter table measurement policy update @'[{"IsEnabled": true, "Source": 
"raw", "Query": "rawtransform()", "IsTransactional": false, 
"PropagateIngestionProperties": false}]'
```

For the staging table you can define a [shorter caching period](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/alter-table-cache-policy-command), if the data is not queried so often.